# Drawing line in UITableViewCell (without using drawRect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drawrect

I have a UITableViewCell in which I would like to draw some lines (say a 2pt line at 1/3rd from top of the TableCell covering the whole width). The lines would always be in the same place within the tableview cell.

One straightforward solution is to just have a `-drawRect` method that will use `CGContextStrokePath` to draw the line. But that seems to be like an overkill since it would call drawRect everytime which is inefficient.

I would think that there would be a way to be able to *cache* it somehow, so that all tableview cells are created with the lines by default. One way I can think of is to create 2pt*2pt png file and add it to a UIImageView on top of the tableview cell. Any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Add this code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just adjust y position og this image view-

```
UIImageView *seperatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 49, 320, 1)];
seperatedImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[cellBackView addSubview:seperatedImageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is, to add a `UIView` and set its background color. For example:

```
 UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 2)] autorelease];
 lineView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor grayColor];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: Ofc you can also do that in the storyboard, so all cells have it (and reusable cells should have a better performance than adding it in code to every cell manually)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `UIView` like a subView of your `UITableViewCell`.